# ERROR ITMS-90129: "The bundle uses a bundle name or display name that is already taken."

Tags: macos, xamarin, xamarin.ios, app-store, publishing

I've tried 3 different bundle name and the error still the same, i searched in the app store and all the 3 names doesn't exist, someone know what could i do to fix this ?

Comment: Doesn't have to be a published app for the bundle/display name to be already reserved. Also are you only changing the bundle name and not the display name?, as the error is referring to either one as the problem.

Comment: I changed the display name to, i created another app in app store, but it still the same.

Comment: Keep the bundle ID in `iTunes Connect` the same as the bundle ID in your `project`. You should change the both side and use a `unique` string.

Comment: @SushiHangover The display name needs to be unique as well? I thought you could name your app "TakenName - Additional details to make the name unique" and use "TakenName" as the displayed name on the home screen.

Answer (score 2):

Change to Product Name also - packing -> Product Name

Answer (score 0):

I had to make sure that the `CFBundleName` was unique. Best way is probably to have your company name as part of it.